# Set date_select with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got this field in my form:

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :date %><br>
        <%= f.date_select :date,{order: [:day, :month, :year]}, class: "datepicker task_date" %>
</div>
```

If my form is submitted and I open the form again the previous date that is entered is selected in the date_select

Now i write some jquerythat remove the value :

```
$('.task_date').val('');
```

But now i want that after the form is submitted the date_select have the current time selected.

```
$('.task_date').datepicker("defaultDate", new Date() );
```

I've got this but that doesn't work, anyone have an idea?

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

This is what works for me.

```
//Get current date
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

//Set date back to current date
$("#task_date_3i.datepicker.task_date").val(day);
$("#task_date_2i.datepicker.task_date").val(month);
$("#task_date_1i.datepicker.task_date").val(year);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method:

```
$('.task_date').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer, i tried it but still doesn't work, cause of the format?